# Derivative calculation stuck with two results

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to calculate derivative for this function, and I'm stuck with two results. Can anyone help please?

My derivative:

$$z = \frac{y^3}{3} - \frac{2}{y^3} + \frac{y}{2}$$

The first result I get is $0$

The second is:
$$y'(z) = \frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{2}- \frac{6}{y^2} - y^2}$$

I have no idea where the problem is, thanks.

Update, I have worked for about last 40 minutes on this solution:

$$z'(y) = \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{6}{y^4} + y^2$$

How does that look, I really hope better :D

Comment: A possible typo:  the "x^2" should, I think, be "y^4".

Comment: Yea, sorry, it is  y`(z) = - 1 / ( -( 1 / 2) - (6 / x^4 ) - y^2), is this the correct one?

Comment: I also think it should be a y instead of an x, not just a 4 instead of a 2.

Comment: Ok, I will try again. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Also, can you explain what your reasoning is for the two results?  I don't see how you got 0 for the first result.  I'm also curious how you wound up with all the (unnecessary!) minus signs in the second.

Comment: http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/tempimagedir/eqn3797.png I got this, you were correct. I will start with stating that I'm very bad at math, and teacher gave me few samples, and I simply calculated the results based on those samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's updated solution looks quite nice (three cheers for learning TeX!).  The original formula expresses $z$ as a function of $y$, so the derivative with respect to $y$, $z'(y)$, is correctly given (although it's slightly disconcerting to reverse the order of the powers of $y$).  Assuming the initial question concerned implicit differentiation, it's more or less correct to write 
$$y'(z)={dy\over dz} = {1\over dz/dy} = {1\over z'(y)}$$
hence the OP's second result, modulo a typo, is also OK, although it's a mystery where all the minus signs came from.  It's also a mystery (to me) how the OP got $0$ for a first result.

Comment: I belive I just made some crazy mistakes, but now I got it. Thanks.